# Bazel build with OpenCV 3.3 dependencies

Tags: c++, opencv, bazel

I'm trying to use Bazel to compile and distribute an OpenCV based C++ code and I'm facing an issue I can't resolve.

I build and install OpenCV 3.3 from sources, on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with CUDA support (CUDA 8). I install it in the standard directory /usr/local.

Given it, I created my project with this WORKSPACE file :

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "opencv",
    path = "/usr/local",
    build_file = "opencv.BUILD",
)
```

The opencv.BUILD contains :

```
cc_library(
    name = "opencv",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.so*"]),
    hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.hpp"]),
    includes = ["include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"], 
    linkstatic = 1,
)
```

And I can use it in my own code using :

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cc"],
    deps = [
        "@opencv//:opencv"
    ],
)
```

but some source files in OpenCV, as :

```
/usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp
```

includes headers file from the same directory, like :

```
#include "general.h"
```

And when I build with Bazel, I get this error :

```
ERROR: /home/damien/main/BUILD:1:1: C++ compilation of rule '//main:main' failed (Exit 1)
In file included from external/opencv/include/opencv2/flann.hpp:48:0,
                 from external/opencv/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:62,
                 from main/main.cc:1:
external/opencv/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp:38:21: fatal error: general.h: No such file or directory
```

(general.h is in the same directory as flann_base.hpp).

If I rewrite the #include directive as :

```
#include "opencv2/flann/general.h"
```

It compiles well. But this is not a convenient solution.

So my question is : is there a way to tell Bazel to look for headers in the same directory as the "current" file in this library ? I look upon every C++ directives of Bazel, but I don't see anything to achieve it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, shame on me. I have to import *.h :

```
cc_library(
    name = "opencv",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.so*"]),
    hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.hpp", "include/**/*.h"]),
    includes = ["include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"], 
    linkstatic = 1,
)
```

Comment: This whole Q&A pair helped me a lot man! working like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case using opencv4 and Damien setup I was getting the error while including *highgui.hpp*:

```
 external/opencv/include/opencv4/opencv2/highgui.hpp:46:10: fatal
 error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory  #include
 "opencv2/core.hpp"
```

I could fix it adjusting the includes adding opencv4:

```
cc_library(
    name = "opencv",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.so*"]),
    hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.hpp", "include/**/*.h"]),
    includes = ["include/opencv4"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"], 
    linkstatic = 1,
)
```